# How to use DataAdapter to call a stored procedure in C# with variable parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, connection

I am calling the following code in C# to fill a **dataAdapter** with a given stored procedure **"sp1_name"**. The problem is that I want to call different stored procedures with different parameters. **(All SP's do a SELECT)**
Let's suppose that my stored procedure name is **"SP_SOMESP"**, then everything works fine.

Let's suppose that my stored procedure name is **"SP_SOMESP @Month= 10, @Year = 2010"**, then it doesn't work. It throws an exception that cannot find this stored procedure.

Any solutions?

Thanks!

```
//First Connection - SP1
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sp1_name, con)) //sp1_name = NAME + PARAMETERS
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(results2);
                }

            }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Issue:**
 Parameters in a stored procedure shouldn't be included along with its name
**Second Issue:**
 Having a space in names of stored procedure isn't a good practice.
And for code behind

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String Here"))
{ 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_SomeName", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //the 2 codes after this comment is where you assign value to the parameters you
    //have on your stored procedure from SQL
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MONTH", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "someValue";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@YEAR", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "SomeYear";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    SqlDataSet ds = new SqlDataSet();
    da.Fill(ds); //this is where you put values you get from the Select command to a 
  //dataset named ds, reason for this is for you to fetch the value from DB to code behind

    foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) // this is where you run through the dataset and get values you want from it.
    {
       someTextBox.Text = dr["Month"].ToString(); //you should probably know this code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add in the parameters programmatically, see [SqlCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

It would be something like

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", 10);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", 2010);
```

This would be after the command is declared and before it is executed.

If you find that you need to delcare the data type, then try it this way

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 10;
```

Comment: You really should always declare the datatype. It eliminates the possibility of .net getting it wrong. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: True, this is a good practice.  A comment on that article mentions that this isn't a big deal when using a stored procedure, as the stored procedure will have the parameter already declared to be of a specific type.

Comment: Yes agreed. I personally prefer to always specify datatypes and size. And you don't have to document why you used AddWithValue this time and Add that time. :)

Comment: You're right, it can only help if you're more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
using (SQLCommand cmd = new SQLCommand())
{
cmd.CommandText = "SP_SOMESP";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Month", 10);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", 2010);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = con;
}
using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
  dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
  dataAdapter.Fill(results2);
}
```